# Loop through first n elements of array in OCaml

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I have the following function in OCaml which sums the first `c` elements in an array passed as an argument:

```
let rec sum_array c a =
    if c < 0 then 0
    else a.(c) + sum_array (c - 1) a;;
```

I happen to know what the array `a` is in advanced, so I'd like to set this. I tried:

```
fun c -> let int_array = [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] in
    let rec sum_array c =
        if c < 0 then 0
        else int_array.(c) + sum_array (c - 1);;
```

But OCaml complains with an ambiguous 'Error: Syntax error', which is super helpful.

1. How can I fix this function definition? How can I specify that I want the value of `sum_array` returned?
2. How can I get OCaml to report more helpful error messages?

Answer (score 5):

In some sense your problem is that you're adding `fun c -> ...` in the wrong place.

Say you had a function like this:

```
let f count =
    (count + 72 - 1) / 72
```

If you imagine that the hard-coded value 72 is something you would like to pre-calculate, you can rewrite the function as follows:

```
let f =
    let line_length = 72 in
    fun count -> (count + line_length - 1) / line_length
```

Your code is placing the array before the body of the function, but it should be inside it, between the `let` and a new inner function definition.

Your case is particularly tricky because your function is recursive. So you can't switch over to the `fun c -> ...` form. Instead you can retain the original let-based definition locally. For the contrived example, it would look like this:

```
let f =
    let line_length = 72 in
    let inner_f count =
        (count + line_length - 1) / line_length
    in
    inner_f
```

(As a side comment, your code sums the first c+1 elements of the array, not the first c elements.)

Answer (score 3):

The error message appears at the `;;` because a `let` without `in` is only permissible as the outermost statement. To make your expression evaluate, you need to add `in sum_array c`:

```
fun c -> let int_array = [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] in
    let rec sum_array c =
        if c < 0 then 0
        else int_array.(c) + sum_array (c - 1)
    in sum_array c;;
- : int -> int = <fun>
```

This can be simplified by dropping the abstraction on `c`:

```
let int_array = [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] in
    let rec sum_array c =
        if c < 0 then 0
        else int_array.(c) + sum_array (c - 1)
    in sum_array;;
```

In both cases, sum_array is not bound on the top level. Either you bind it with another `let sum_array =`..., you pull the binding of `int_array` inside of the definition of `sum_array`(like @Jeffrey Scofield proposed), or you bind `int_array` on the top level before you define `sum_array`:

```
let int_array = [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |]

let rec sum_array c =
        if c < 0 then 0
        else int_array.(c) + sum_array (c - 1)
;;
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer may seem a little lengthy, but that's only because I see from your error certain lack of understanding in some basic notions of OCaml. This may be a good chance to clear things up a little.

## Scope and Sequencing in OCaml

You may or may not already understand this topic already. I still have to elaborate on this a little since they are the basis of what follows.

Think of how you would test your code:

```
let rec sum_array c a =
    if c < 0 then 0
    else a.(c) + sum_array (c - 1) a
in
sum_array 2 [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |]         ;;
```

I assume you are familiar with ordinary programming languages. To put it in a Java way:

```
//Java version
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = a + b;
```

Would be translated into OCaml code of:

```
(* OCaml version *)
let a = 1 in
let b = 1 in
let c = a + b in
c       ;;
```

They are not all that different. At first glance, OCaml's way of representing sequencing (that is `;`) seems tedious. But as your journey of functional programming goes on, you will understand the importance of such an mechanism more.

## Faulty Logic

As the result shows:

```
let rec sum_array c a =
    if c < 0 then 0
    else a.(c) + sum_array (c - 1) a
in
sum_array 2 [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] ;;
(* - : int = 6   *)
```

The logic you did here is a little faulty. Your function added one more element than necessary. The fix is simple:

```
let rec sum_array c a =
    if c = 0 then 0
    else a.(c - 1) + sum_array (c - 1) a
in
sum_array 2 [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] ;;
(* - : int = 3  *)
```

And it works right now. The function now sums up the first `n` elements of the array.

## How to Store [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] into the Function so that it only takes the argument `n` ?

I assume this is what you mean by saying : I happen to know the array a in advance.

And here is simple codes to do that with very little change:

```
let rec sum_array c =
let a = [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] in
    if c = 0 then 0
    else a.(c - 1) + sum_array (c - 1)          ;;
```

Then you can run it just like this:

```
sum_array 3;;
(* - : int = 6   *)
```

See the little change here is just use another `let ... in` to hardcode the definition of `a` inside the function definition. This is exactly how one would do the same thing in java.

## All being said, What is wrong with Your Own Code?

Your code:

```
fun c -> let int_array = [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] in
    let rec sum_array c =
        if c < 0 then 0
        else int_array.(c) + sum_array (c - 1);;
```

fails for two reasons:

- **Shadowing**: It looks like that this function takes `c` as argument, but actually it does nothing with `c` after it's passed in. That's because you have another same name argument `c` for your function `sum_array` (which is a helper function for the outer overall function), and this argument shadowed the binding, or definition of the outmost argumet `c`.
- Scope: within the definition of this big function, you defined `int_array` and `sum_array`. But they are both local names, and you did not return anything. Recall that the return value for a function is the value of the entire expression on the right side of the arrow. And what is that value in this case? Nothing, other than the definitions of a few local variables, which expires as soon as the function ends.

This is the right code:

```
fun arg -> let int_array = [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] in
        let rec sum_array c =
            if c < 0 then 0
            else int_array.(c) + sum_array (c - 1)
        in sum_array arg
```

But there is another problem, this function above, is a function. That means it's a value. And if you don't bind a value to a variable right now, you either use it right now, or you lose track of it. So the better thing to do here is:

```
let sum_first_n = 
fun arg -> let int_array = [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] in
        let rec sum_array c =
            if c < 0 then 0
            else int_array.(c) + sum_array (c - 1)
        in sum_array arg        ;;
```

And now you can call it like any other function.

Of course I am still using your faulty logic in this code. Fixing that, we have:

```
let sum_first_n = 
fun arg -> let int_array = [| 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 |] in
        let rec sum_array c =
            if c = 1 then int_array.(0)
            else int_array.(c - 1) + sum_array (c - 1)
        in sum_array arg        ;;

sum_first_n 3;;
(* - : int = 6        *)
```

And now everything works right.

## How to do it More Functionally ?

What if you are given an argument of a List rather than an array? How would you do it without mutation?

This is good practice to help you get quicker on track of OCaml.

Here is the code:

```
let rec sum_array c l = match c,l with
    | _, [] | 0, _ -> 0
    | (_, hd::tl) -> hd + sum_array (c-1) tl
in sum_array 4 [1;2;3;4;5;6]        ;;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted, but thank you for such a compete answer!